# C# Assembly Reference problems

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, c#-3.0, custom-controls

I will surely go mad if I don't know what is the reason for this :) :

I have several projects in my solution. The problem I'm getting is in a solution where I'm adding reference of another.

In 1 project I have my custom controls (purely .cs files) and another solution is test pages which are only ASPX pages (without any code behind file - since the entire operation is performed by the controls)

Now the problem is when I added the reference of my Custom Controls project to my Web pages project, the code which I wrote in custom control is not getting affected. I added a new property for my custom textbox control which is not coming in the intellisense in my HTML markup and the break point I'm setting is not getting a hit (inside custom controls code).

This is **working fine in .NET 3.5 Framework**. (We have 2 branches; one is 3.5 and another is 4.0) but is **NOT working in .NET Framework 4.0**. **I'm using Windows 2008 Server R2**.

What I have did uptil now:

- Checked the target framework for both the projects (4.0 for both).
- Copied and pasted the assembly where ever required.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding your "Custom Control" to ASP.NET project Toolbox panel in Visual Studio (It worked for me once!).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm working in an integrated environment. Cannot use this approach. Just wanted to know if there are any issues with the DLL referencing. I checked everything and it seems to be alright...

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I got it worked through a idiotic way.. as we know which is always in case of Microsoft Solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Are the reference project's dll falling in bin folder after build/rebuild?
Have you registered your control in your ASPX page?
Also, when you are saying you have reference to project then what is the reason behing copying and pasting?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. No the project is getting build successfully. Yes I have registered my control in web.config. I just tried copying and pasting the DLLs to check..

Comment: If you have project reference then you dont need dlls to copy paste. Do rebuild. It will copy files for you. Also, do this for debug profile so that PDBs also get copy and you can debug.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I got it worked through a idiotic way.. as we know which is always in case of Microsoft Solutions.